# get the zero based index of tds onclick in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi have a table that has many rows

The first row has `<th>`s then all the following rows contain `<td>`s

If I use the script below and click on the the first row with `<td>`s in it I get an alert saying 1. How do I make it say zero with out subtracting one. I thought that using "has(td)" would work?

```
$('td').click(function(){

   var s = $(this).parents('table tr:has(td)').index();
   alert(s);

});

<table border="1" width="400px" height="200px">
    <tr>
        <th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td> if I click here it must alert 0
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td> if I click here it must alert 1
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td> if I click here it must alert 2
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td> if I click here it must alert 3
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td> if I click here it must alert 4
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: wrong markup . you write text outside of `<td>` tags

Comment: Surely `$(this).parent().index() - 1` is way more efficient than any solution that involves selectors with `:has` or `:contains` or whatever else. I find it easier to read, too. (But your code didn't work because `.index()` with no parameters returns the element's index in relation to its siblings in the DOM, not in relation to other elements in the jQuery object.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the a selector to `.index()` to filter out the siblings

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var s = $(this).parent().index('tr:has(td)');
    alert(s);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nAhE3/